# Jersey Client - Post request giving error "Content-Type header must be application/vnd.api+json"

Tags: jersey, jersey-client

I am trying to test post request using jersey client, although i am setting header as below i am getting error in response that Content-Type header must be application/vnd.api+json. Please refer below code:

```
String input = "{\r\n" + 
                "  \"data\": {\r\n" + 
                "    \"attributes\": {\r\n" + 
                "      \"email\": \"emailqwszxwe@example.com\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"password\": \"password\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"avatar_url\": \"http://example.com/example.png\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"first-name\": \"John\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"last-name\": \"Doe\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"details\": \"example\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"contact\": \"example\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"facebook-url\": \"http://facebook.com/facebook\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"twitter-url\": \"http://twitter.com/twitter\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"instagram-url\": \"http://instagram.com/instagram\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"google-plus-url\": \"http://plus.google.com/plus.google\",\r\n" + 
                "      \"original-image-url\": \"https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2013/11/23/16/25/birds-216412_1280.jpg\"\r\n" + 
                "    },\r\n" + 
                "    \"type\": \"user\"\r\n" + 
                "  }\r\n" + 
                "}";
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://qe.events.infostretch.com/api");

    String content = "application/vnd.api+json";
    Response response = target.path("/v1/users").request().header("Content-Type", content).post(Entity.json(input));
```

Output :

````
{"errors": [{"source": "", "detail": "Content-Type header must be application/vnd.api+json", "title": "InvalidRequestHeader", "status": 415}], "jsonapi": {"version": "1.0"}}```

I am not able to understand why it is not showing correct response???

i am using below dependency:

<dependency> <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId> 
<artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId> 
<version>2.30.1</version> </dependency>
````

Comment: That's not a standard error output. Without info about the server implementation, it's hard to tell what's going on. The client request looks fine. You can even add the LoggingFeature to the request to make sure the header is actually sent out as you have it.

Comment: i tried to log request details, i got below
`INFO: 1 * Sending client request on thread main
1 > POST http://qe.events.infostretch.com/api/v1/users
1 > Content-Type: application/json
{"data":{"attributes":{"email":"asdfgv4wv94m@example.com"...`

content type is application/json instead of what i am passing